# Ajax webmethod, returning JSOn data

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

I am having some issues with a Webmethod (c#) populating a JQuery DataTable table with JSON data.

Ajax call:

```
function loadTable(message) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TestBed.aspx/ValueDateSummary",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ senderBIC: senderBIC }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");

                    alert(err.Message);

                },
                success: function (msg) {

                    var data = msg.d;
                    alert(data["counter"]);
                    alert(data);
                    alert(typeof msg);
                    var otable = $("#test").dataTable({
                       // "sAjaxDataProp": msg.d,
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "mDataProp": "counter" },
                            { "mDataProp": "SessionID" },
                            { "mDataProp": "MsgType" }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        };
```

No errors, but the datatable is empty.

Here are the results of the alerts

> alert(data["counter"]) = UNDEFINED
>
> alert(data) = [{"counter":3,"SessionID":"1","MsgType":"103","ValueDate":"2007-08-01","Sender":"1"}, {"counter":7,"SessionID":"2","MsgType":"103","ValueDate":"2009-05-26","Sender":"2"}]
>
> alert(typeof msg) = OBJECT

any ideas why my table is empty?

* EDIT ***
THIS IS THE FINAL SUCCESS METHOD WHICH WORKED

```
success: function (msg) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);

                    $("#test").dataTable({
                        "aaData": data,
                        "aoColumns": [{
                            "mDataProp": "counter"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp": "SessionID"
                        }, {
                            "mDataProp": "MsgType"
                        }]
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never settings the data of the `oTable`...

You have to give it an `Array of Arrays (var object = [][])`:

**You can either do** it as [ajax](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) and put your `$ajax` code into the [fnServerData](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/732/using-fnserverdata-if-present-with-sajaxsource-to-get-remote-data/p1) function

**Or do the following:** (*taken from [example from DataTables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)*)

```
function loadTable(message) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TestBed.aspx/ValueDateSummary",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            senderBIC: senderBIC
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");

            alert(err.Message);
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = [];

            $.map(msg.d, function (item) {
                {
                    var row = [];

                    row.push(
                        item.counter,
                        item.SessionID,
                        item.MsgType
                        //Commented out because you didn't include them in your aoColumns declaration, if you want them in the table to access later just make them non-visible.
                        //item.ValueDate,
                        //item.Sender
                    );
                    data.push(row);
                }
            });

            var otable = $("#test").dataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"mDataProp": "counter"},
                    {"mDataProp": "SessionID"},
                    {"mDataProp": "MsgType"}
                ]
            });
        }
    });
}
```

As of `jQuery DataTables 1.7.2` you can use [array of objects as a data source](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) but only with the [ajax source (sAjaxSource)](http://datatables.net/ref#sAjaxSource) and it is slightly slower because it just manually copies it to an `array or arrays`.

Comment: not sure if you can still see these comments after i've approved, but there is a syntax error in the above. Expecting })

Comment: Firebug error: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
[Break On This Error]  

typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );

Comment: i feel like were almost there, must be something so obvious i can't see it :-)

Comment: Do you have the page on a public server? i'm happy to hit it and try to work it out for you, otherwise that's just what it says a type mismatch the variable length isn't a number

Comment: It's not. Which is a shame. I can send you the json data if you'd like?

Comment: yes, please do.  With the json I can see what's happening and make a JSfiddle.

Comment: Ok I'll get this to you tomorrow. Left the office for the day.

Comment: {"d":"[{\"counter\":3,\"SessionID\":\"035700082681090525\",\"MsgType\":\"103\",\"ValueDate\":\"2007-08-01T00:00:00\",\"SenderBIC\":\"123\"},{\"counter\":7,\"SessionID\":\"035700082681090525\",\"MsgType\":\"103\",\"ValueDate\":\"2009-05-26T00:00:00\",\"SenderBIC\":\"123\"}]"}

Comment: i did the following fiddle, and realised that my JSON data was indeed being treated as a string. So, i used JSON.parse on the return and it all worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your success function to the following:

```
var data = msg.d;
alert(data["counter"]);
alert(data);
alert(typeof msg);

var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    rows.push([
        data[i].counter,
        data[i].SessionID,
        data[i].MsgType,
        data[i].ValueDate,
        data[i].Sender
    ]);
}

var otable = $("#test").dataTable({
    "aaData": rows
});
```